# database doesn't allow special chars even after using mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters, mysql-real-escape-string

I have found lots of question like this at `SO` and followed the solution,but didn't work in my case.

I want to insert `+` into database,so I have used

```
$tex5=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_dude,$_POST['text5']);
```

But this doesn't insert `+`.It gives empty space(whitespace) in database.

Please be informed,I'm using `prepared statement` and `parameterized query`.Is it the reason why database doesn't allow `+`?If yes,then how can I fix this?

Thanks for your time.

**Code**

*Javascript*

```
//call con_edi() on first button clicked.insert email on text field and click button would fire off change5()    

function con_edi(){
   document.getElementById("alu").innerHTML="<input type='text'  id='taxi' style='border:1px solid black;'><input type='submit' id='' onclick='change5(taxi.value)' value='change'>";
 }

function change5(s){
   var form=s;
   if(!form.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/)){
      alert("Wrong Email");
   }else{
     //document.write(form);  /*for testing the output*/
     var ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
     ajax.open("post","contact.php",true);
     ajax.setRequestHeader("content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
       if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){

          location.reload();

        }
      }

    ajax.send("text5="+form);
   }
 }
```

*PHP*

```
$tex5=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_dude,$_POST['text5']);
$query6="UPDATE `$database`.`header` SET email=?  WHERE user_id=?";

mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt1, $query6);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, "si", $tex5, $logged_id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
```

Comment: can you show a sample of the data passed in $_POST['text5']; ?

Comment: Shouldnt "si" be removed? Your passing 3 variables, but are expecting 2 from the prepared statement. `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, $tex5, $logged_id);`

Comment: 1. remove `htmlentities`, it is wrong at this point. (You use it when you _output_ data into an HTML context, not before inserting it into the database.) 2. Make a debug output of `$_POST['text5']` using `var_dump()` _before_ those lines of code.

Comment: _“Please be informed,I'm using prepared statement”_ – well then using `mysqli_real_escape_string` is wrong to begin with.

Comment: @DanielMcAssey no,that's correct,because $stmt is a part of`mysqli_stmt` class

Comment: @Ibu here is what I'm posting using `text5` field `lkf+alu@craftwebart.com`

Comment: _“here is what I'm posting”_ – fine, and now show us what your script is _receiving_ please, making the debug output that I asked you for.

Comment: @CBroe as I'm using ajax call to communicate with php,I'm having trouble to dump the var.Pls give me a moment and I'll get back to you.Hope you'll be there for help.Thanks

Comment: @CBroe on javascript function,when I print the inputted data,it gives me exact same data on screen.And,that's what'd I'm sending to database.So,it should be same on php block and should give same result for var_dump.Anyway,I've updated ques.Please have a look.

Comment: _“So,it should be same on php block and should give same result for var_dump”_ – that’s what you’re _assuming_, and you are assuming _wrong_. You failed to URL-encode the value properly – and in a URL encoding context, `+` stands for what? Exactly, a space character. Use `ajax.send("text5="+encodeURIComponent(form))`, and you will get a proper `+` character passed to your script. And in the future – don’t _assume_, but **verify**.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks a lot,BOSS.You saved my life.Hats off.If you want to add this as answer,I would be more than happy to accept,and others might find it helpful as well.Once again,Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly URL-encode the value that you are sending.

Right now, you are sending `text5=lkf+alu@craftwebart.com` – and in this URL context, `+` is the “replacement” character for a space character. That is why your script was inserting the space char into the database, not because there was something wrong with the insertion into the database per se. (Although, as mentioned, using `mysqli_real_escape_string` in combination with prepared statements *is* wrong. `mysqli_real_escape_string` is used to mask special characters that are inserted into the SQL syntax directly, so that they can not be confused with the actual SQL syntax. When using prepared statements with placeholders however, SQL command and data are send to the database separate from each other, so that danger does not exist in this context.)

So, you need to use

```
ajax.send("text5="+encodeURIComponent(form));
```

to send your data to the server. [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) takes care of encoding the data properly for the URL context. It will make the `+` character into `%2B`, so that it can be send in that context safely, and PHP will decode it back to a `+` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It appears you have an additional variable being passed in your prepared statement, you are expecting 2 variables, but you are passing 3, removing "si" from the bind statement should fix it.

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, $tex5, $logged_id);
```

OLD ANSWER: Previous answer which I believe is incorrect (Sorry!):

`mysqli_real_escape_string()` function only removes any special characters, which is what it is doing in your case, what you should be doing is converting those special characters to HTML entities with `htmlentities()`.

```
$tex5=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_dude,htmlentities($_POST['text5']));
```

Which would turn a "`+`" to a "`&#43;`" which should be able to be added to the database.

Comment: still giving same result.

Comment: more info added to ques.Pls have a look

Comment: _“`mysqli_real_escape_string()` function only removes any special characters”_ – no, it doesn’t _remove_ them, it masks/escapes them so that they are safe to be used inside an SQL statement.

Comment: @CBroe, you are correct, no need for htmlentities, I have changed my answer.

Comment: @Coder: Yo, keep it polite … you messed up more than enough yourself with this issue.

Comment: @CBroe sorry man.but his first part of the answer about `$stmt` pissed me off lil bit.Sorry to Daniel and thanks for your time as well,Daniel.

Comment: See, that’s better. Everybody can be wrong sometimes …